# ESLint error: Rules with suggestions must set the `meta.hasSuggestions` property to `true` (no-explicit-any rule)

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-typings, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I am trying to add a rule to my .eslintrc.json to disallow the `any` type.

I added the rule (`"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"`) to my setup:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json", "cypress/tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "import/no-relative-parent-imports": "error",
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "groups": [
          "builtin",
          "external",
          "internal",
          "parent",
          "sibling",
          "index",
          "object"
        ],
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc"
        },
        "newlines-between": "always"
      }
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
    "max-len": [
      2,
      {
        "code": 150,
        "ignorePattern": "^import .*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Failed to compile.

Rules with suggestions must set the `meta.hasSuggestions` property to `true`. `meta.docs.suggestion` is ignored by ESLint.
Occurred while lining <name of file>
Rule: "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any"
```

These are some of the used packages and their version:

```
 "@types/react": "^17.0.45",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.4.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.17",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^4.33.0",
    "axe-core": "^4.4.2",
    "cypress": "^9.6.1",
    "cypress-axe": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "jest-junit": "^13.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0"
```

I saw another post on StackOverflow suggesting to use eslint-plugin-react-hooks for another error but cannot find anything similar for the rule I'm trying to apply. Also, some people mentioned issues with version 8+ of eslint but based on the packages I have it seems I have version: 7.32.0

Adding `meta: {hasSuggestions: true}` doesn't work and gives me the same error as in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336041/set-the-meta-hassuggestions-property-to-true-meta-docs-suggestion-is-igno)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't add that to your config, it's telling you _the rule itself_ isn't correct ([for ESLint 8](https://eslint.org/docs/8.0.0/user-guide/migrating-to-8.0.0#suggestions)).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm getting the same error, and for now I've just disabled that rule.

Comment: Personally, I didn't find the solution but the project I was working on has this rule implemented now. When the rule was implemented, I can see that the following were updated:     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^5.36.1"  - Perhaps updating eslint packages fixed the error because eslint addresses the issues in their most recent releases?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of all `*eslint*` packages -especially `eslint` and `@typescript-eslint/*`- and the error should go away. Be sure to run your package manager's install command such as `npm i`.

Explanation: that *"must set the `meta.hasSuggestions` property"* error was [added in ESLint 8](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/migrate-to-8.0.0#suggestions). Old versions of some ESLint plugins written before that requirement didn't always satisfy it. So if you use a much newer version of ESLint with a much older plugin, you might get that error.

In general, try to always use relatively recent versions of packages. Especially if you're seeing mysterious errors from them. This question is from 2022 but the `package.json` mentions typescript-eslint packages at version 4. typescript-eslint@5 was released in 2021.